# Mongodb pymongo errors DocumentTooLarge

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do the following query:
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75RIo.png)

the problem is `{"id": {"$nin": lista}}`. lista is an array of ids that cointains 1.000.000 ids exceeding 98MB size.
Since Mongodb has a limit of 16MB it seems i cannot send this query without getting the following error: `pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: BSON document too large (107382731 bytes) - the connected server supports BSON document sizes up to 16777216 bytes.`. Something I dont complete understand because the limit is supposted to be for documents inside collections.

My question is: How I can exclude a list/array of ids then?

Comment: Add limit to your documents

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan the documents do not exceed the 16MB size, is the query itselt that surpass that limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try redoing your query via aggregation pipeline (and storing the ids in a collection rather than sending them in the query) but you are right, there is a limit on the query size.

Although I have not personally tested it, it is my impression that the server could technically allow an incoming query up to 48 mb rather than 16 as stated in your message but you would need to find a driver that would also permit 48 mb query size and I don't know off the top of my head which ones would. It is also possible that 48 mb limit only applies to find and modify queries and both find and modify parts are still restricted to 16 mb.